# How to read the contents of a static file

Tags: django, django-views, django-staticfiles

I have the following custom Django filter:

```
@register.filter(name="html2email")
def html2email(value):
    css = "h1{color:#45474D}"

    p = Pynliner()
    return mark_safe(p.from_string(value).with_cssString(css).run())
```

How can I set `css` to read the contents of my static CSS file (in '/static/css/stye.css')?

I would have thought something like: `css = get_file('static/css/style.css')` like with `get_template` but it doesn't seem to exist?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The static files are in `settings.STATIC_ROOT`, and you can open and read them from there with the normal Python file `open` command.

However, I would question why you are doing this. If you need access to a file in your code, it shouldn't really be a static file.